# Managing the IsEnabled property of a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a xaml window in my program that has a button called "Save", and a `textBox`. I also have a ViewModel for this window. Inside the ViewModel I have a `string` property for the `textBox`, and a `bool` property for `IsEnabled` on the button. I would like the button to only be enabled when there is text inside the `textBox`.

**xaml:**

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding SaveEnabled}" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
```

**ViewModel properties:**

```
//Property for Name
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => Name);

        if (value == null)
        {
            _saveEnabled = false;
            NotifyPropertyChange(() => SaveEnabled);
        }
        else
        {
            _saveEnabled = true;
            NotifyPropertyChange(() => SaveEnabled);
        }
    }
}

//Prop for Save Button -- IsEnabled
public bool SaveEnabled
{
    get { return _saveEnabled; }
    set
    {
        _saveEnabled = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SaveEnabled);
    }
}
```

I think my main question here is, where do I put the code concerning this problem? As you can see above, I've tried to put it into the `setter` of the `Name` property, but it comes back with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Name);
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SaveEnabled);
    }
}

public bool SaveEnabled
{
    get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name); }
}
```

**EDIT:** Add this to your xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">...</TextBox>
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not create any change.

Comment: Is you viewmodel attached? Also check your xaml... usually this works. In fact, even your original implementation should work, but there may be something broken with your bindings.

Comment: I do not receive any binding errors. My viewModel is the `DataContext` of the correct xaml window.

Comment: Ah, check the edit, I think you have to tell your textbox to send update events for every keystroke. I just tested it, seems to work.

Comment: Bingo, that was it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Although this works, you should really focus in ICommands - especialli in WPF

Answer (score 2):

Use ICommands that are used in MVVM:

```
private ICommand _commandSave;
public ICommand CommandSave
{
    get { return _commandSave ?? (_commandSave = new SimpleCommand<object, object>(CanSave, ExecuteSave)); }
}

private bool CanSave(object param)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name);
}
private void ExecuteSave(object param)
{

}
```

And then use the following in the XAML Code

```
<TextBox Command="{Binding CommandSave}" ... />
```

Depending on the Framework that you use the command class works differen. For a generic implementation I suggest [Relay Command](http://snipplr.com/view/13642/relaycommand-class/).